# How to quickly insert sequential numbers?

Tags: gimp, text, numbering

Working in Gimp, I frequently need to label different parts of a diagram with sequential numbers (say, 1 to 30 or so). Is there any tool in Gimp which can make this more efficient (ideally 1-click on each spot with a number)? Alternatively, is there any other software that can streamline this?

Comment: Could you use another app instead? I'm sure there are many apps that can do that easier than Gimp... Though I can only remember one annotation app with this specific functionality: [Snagit](https://www.techsmith.com/screen-capture.html) (Windows, Mac). It does come with a standalone editor if you don't have any need to capture the screen using it. [**Video showcasing the step tool**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAzKeOhyOD4)

Comment: @Joonas: I'd definitely be open to other software, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [ofn-points-sequence](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).

Basically you create a path with the Path tool:

[image]

Then call the script to generate the numbers:

[image]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you so much!